Solving the series $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)}$
Hi I want to solve this series
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)}$$ and when I try to use partial fraction from the denominator I get
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \left(\frac{1}{6k}-\frac{1}{2(k+1)}+\frac{1}{2(k+2)}-\frac{1}{6(k+3)}\right)$$
Now I amplified the 2nd and 3rd  fractions with 3 so that the denominator is 6
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \left(\frac{1}{6k}-\frac{3}{6(k+1)}+\frac{3}{6(k+2)}-\frac{1}{6(k+3)}\right)$$
Is this correct? What do I do from here? I'm stuck and I don't know how to solve this.
The answer to this series exercise is $$\frac{1}{18}$$.
How do I reach from my steps to that answer? I'm confused!

Take $\frac{1}{6}$ common, and then write out the first few terms of each series. You'll notice, that a large majority of them cancel out, which can be 'proven' by first separating each fraction as a separate sum, and then changing the index so that each sum has a $\frac{1}{k}$ term inside,and from there it becomes obvious

The sum is actually indepentent from $n$? If I'm not missing something for $n=1$ the sum becomes $\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{2\cdot 2}+\frac{1}{2\cdot 3}-\frac{1}{6\cdot 4}=\frac{1}{24}$ but for $n=2$ i get $\frac{1}{20}$.

Your idea is correct, you are only missing one small observation to finish. You used partial fractions to find $$\sum_{k\geq 1} \frac{1}{k(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)} = \sum_{k\geq 1} \left(\frac{1}{6k}-\frac{1}{2(k+1)}+\frac{1}{2(k+2)}-\frac{1}{6(k+3)}\right)$$ 
We can index shift the sums on the right to get:
$$\sum_{k\geq 1} \frac{1}{6k} - \sum_{k\geq 4} \frac{1}{6k} + \sum_{k\geq 3} \frac{1}{2k} - \sum_{k\geq 2} \frac{1}{2k}$$
Notice how most of the terms cancel, we are left with,
$$\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{12}+\frac{1}{18} - \frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{18}$$ as desird.
